# How to create AMI of my EC2 instance through API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to automatically create an AMI for my EC2 instance through a cron job being executed at my node server.Is there any aws API which can help me in creating that?
I googled my way till [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateImage.html).But I am getting the following error when I trynna hit
'`https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=CreateImage&Description=demo-server-new-ami&InstanceId=i-test&Name=Demo-Server-through-api&NoReboot=true`'.
I am open to implement any other solution for automatically generating the AMI at egular intervals.

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidAction</Code><Message>The action CreateImage is not valid for this web service.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>5ac466db-5ab0-433b-8696-5564ab78f52e</RequestID></Response>
```

Comment: Use any of the API language, e.g. AWS CLI, boto3, etc. Direct HTTPS request is difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

To Create AMI/Image from your EC2 instance, You can use AWS CLi command.

Example:

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id <INSTANCE_ID> --name "My server" --description "An AMI for my server" --region <REGIOn>
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: I cant.I need to create AMI from my node api.

Comment: You are right. The implementation shown in AWS Docs is giving me the same error of `InvalidAction`.
I am not sure about node api, But you can try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#createImage-property and if it works then you can update the answer accordingly so that others can get the benefit of this.
Thanks

Comment: I have updated the url in above comment for node api.